# The integer remainder of division is not obtained

Tags: php

The integer remainder from division is not obtained. The number from 7 to 30 lies in `$interval->d`. I always get 0, why is that?

```
$w = $interval->d % 7;
$result .= $interval->format($w == 1 ? "%w week ago" : "%w weeks ago");
```

Comment: % 7 - remainder after dividing, so you want $w = ($interval->d - ($interval->d % 7))/7;

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Sure it's not a floor of a division you want? What you get is the odd days in the last week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want the floor of a normal division.

```
$w = floor($interval->d / 7); // $interval->d = 30

echo $w; //4
```

What you got was the remainder of the division which is the days in the last week.